# auto-run for applescript editor

Tags: macos, applescript, usb-drive, autorun

Can I make an apple script that auto runs when I put in my flash drive? I want to be able to do this so that when I put my flash drive in the computer at school I can make my presentation automatically play to save time and so i don't have to go through all my files in front of the class. We use macs at school and I have a mac.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way using plain AppleScript to receive events when a drive is plugged in.

What you could do is create a poll timer that checks for the drive at a specified interval:

```
repeat
    set driveName to "YOURDRIVENAME"
    set driveExists to (do shell script "ls /Volumes | grep " & driveName)
    if driveExists contains driveName then
        -- do whatever
    end if
    delay 5
end repeat
```

I wrote that off the top of my head, and I haven't tested it, but something along those lines should work. `delay 5` tells the script to wait 5 seconds before polling again, change this to suit your needs. I haven't tried anything like this with AppleScript before so it may be taxing on resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can activate a Folder Action applescript to watch for newly attached volumes.

Duplicate the script */Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts/add - new item alert.scpt* and modify the copy to open your presentation or what-have-you.

Activate the script via */Library/Scripts/Folder Actions/Configure Folder Actions* (a link to */System/Library/CoreServices/Folder Actions Setup.app*):

1. Launch *Configure Folder Actions* and enable it with the top check box.
2. Click the left plus sign to add a folder to watch.
3. Hit ⇧g (command-shift-g) to navigate to an invisible folder. Type: **/Volumes** and hit enter
4. Hit Enter or click the Open button without selecting anything to attach to the /Volumes directory itself.
5. Choose your modified *add - new item alert.scpt* from the Attach pane.